# Simplify: $\frac{a^4+3a^2b^2+b^4-2a^3b-2ab^3}{a^4+a^2b^2+b^4}$

Tags: factoring

Simplify, $$\cfrac{a^4+3a^2b^2+b^4-2a^3b-2ab^3}{a^4+a^2b^2+b^4}$$
Maybe this is basic, but I'm stuck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numerator $=(a^2+b^2)^2-2ab(a^2+b^2)+(ab)^2=(a^2+b^2-ab)^2$

The denominator $=(a^2+b^2)^2-(ab)^2=?$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{a^4+3a^2b^2+b^4-2a^3b-2ab^3}{a^4+a^2b^2+b^4}$$ $$=\frac{(a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4)+a^2b^2-2a^3b-2ab^3}{(a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4)-a^2b^2}$$
$$=\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2-2ab(a^2+b^2)+a^2b^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2-a^2b^2}$$
$$=\frac{\overbrace{(a^2+b^2)^2-a^2b^2}\overbrace{-2ab(a^2+b^2)+2a^2b^2}}{(a^2+b^2-ab)(a^2+b^2+ab)}$$
$$=\frac{(a^2+b^2-ab)(a^2+b^2+ab)-2ab(a^2+b^2-ab)}{(a^2+b^2-ab)(a^2+b^2+ab)}$$
$$=\frac{(a^2+b^2-ab)[(a^2+b^2+ab)-2ab]}{(a^2+b^2-ab)(a^2+b^2+ab)}$$
$$=\frac{a^2+b^2-ab}{a^2+b^2+ab}$$